# Adding an attribute to the root XML element when serializing an object

Tags: c#, xml

I have an object that I serialize into an XML file. Everything works as expected, but I'm wanting to add a Version attribute to the root element.

What's the best way to do this?

Here's an example of how I'm serializing:

```
MyProgram newProgram = new MyProgram()
{
    ValueA = "A value.",
    ValueB = "B value.",
    ValueC = "C value."
};

XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyProgram));
StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileName);
xmlSerializer.Serialize(streamWriter, newProgram);
streamWriter.Close();
```

Right now, my XML looks something like this:

```
<MyProgram>
    <ValueA>A value.</ValueA>
    <ValueB>B value.</ValueB>
    <ValueC>C value.</ValueC>
</MyProgram>
```

But I'd like to have this:

```
<MyProgram Version="1.0">
    <ValueA>A value.</ValueA>
    <ValueB>B value.</ValueB>
    <ValueC>C value.</ValueC>
</MyProgram>
```

Thanks!

Comment: And do you want to (can you) add a Version property to MyProgram?

Comment: Yes, I'm wanting to add a Version attribute to MyProgram but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

**First**

Modify your XML to be like this, assuming you have a concrete class and not an anonymous one

```
[XmlRoot("MyProgram")]//sepcifies the name of the root element
public class MyProgram
{
  [XmlAttribute("Version")]//name not required unless you want to change output to something different
   public string Version{get;set;}
   [XmlElement("ValueA")]//again, name not required if the name is the same
   public ValueA ValueA{get;set;}
   ....
}
```

Then creating the MyProgram class as you specified will give you the desired output, also note that you might need to add XML tags to the ValueA/B/C classes if the end result is not as desired.

**The second** 
Serialize the XML data to a string, and use simple Regex/String manipulation to insert the desired value and then save the string to the desired location

**Third**

You can either use XElement to query your XML string /Create it and then set the Version attribute

```
XElement x = XElement.Load("Your XML location");
var yourRoot = x.Descendants("MyProgram").FirstOrDefaul();
yourRoot.SetAttributeValue("Version","1.0");
yourRoot.Save("Your XML location");
```